# The value of 2d dynamic array is getting corrupted during loop iteration

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, multidimensional-array

The value of 2d dynamic array is getting corrupted during loop iteration,For example in loop Decision/iteration 16 all values are displayed correctly but when comes Decision/iteration 26 the array location KillRate[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwxiJ.jpg) is being corrupted even during iteration no values are being assigned to KillRate array.As illustrated by the images attached.

```
for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        x[i][j]=0;
        y[i][j]=0;
    }
}
x[0][0]=0;
x[0][1]=.33;
x[0][2]=.75;


x[1][0]=0;
x[1][1]=.33;
x[1][2]=.75;

x[2][0]=0;
x[2][1]=.33;
x[2][2]=.75;

x[3][0]=0;
x[3][1]=.33;
x[3][2]=.75;



    void Display()
{
    int StageValue;
    int DecisionValue;
    double long Minimum;
    TreeNodeType *T;
    cout<<"**********************@@@@@DISPLAY STARTED@@@@**************************************"<<endl;
    for(TreeNodeType *p=Headptr;p!=NULL;p=p->FirstChild)
    {

        KillRate[3][0]=0;
        KillRate[3][1]=.33;
        KillRate[3][2]=.75;


        DecisionValue=-1;
        cout<<"\n\n\n"<<endl;
        for(TreeNodeType *q=p;q!=NULL;q=q->Siblings)
        {
            if(q==Headptr)
            {
                q->PestPopulation=pestpop;
            }
            else
            {

                StageValue=q->stage-1;
                DecisionValue=DecisionValue+1;  
                if(DecisionValue==(noOfDecisions))
                {
                    DecisionValue=0;
                }

                double C1=KillRate[StageValue][DecisionValue];
                double K1=Cost[StageValue][DecisionValue];
                cout<<"Stage Value/Decision Value"<<StageValue<<"/"<<DecisionValue<<endl;
                q->PestPopulation=q->Parent->PestPopulation;
                 long double a=(1 - C1);

                 long double b=(PI)*(q->PestPopulation);
                 long double c=(K1)*(this->area);
                 for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
                 {  

                     for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
                     {
                                 cout<<"KillRate:"<<KillRate[i][j]<<" ";//THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE THROUGH ITERATION ARRAY IS BEING DISPLAYED
                     }
                 cout<<endl;
                 }

                cout<<a<<"*"<<b<<"+"<<c<<endl;
                q->Loss= (a*b)+ c;
                TotalLoss[q->stage-1][q->Decision-1]=q->Loss + q->Parent->Loss;
                q->PestPopulation=(1-C1)*(q->PestPopulation)*(this->growthrate);
                cout<<"Stage= "<<q->stage<<", Decision= "<<q->Decision<<",  PestPop="<<q->PestPopulation<<", Loss ="<<q->Loss<<endl<<endl;  


                if(q->Loss>Minimum)
                {
                    Minimum=q->Loss;
                    T=q->Parent;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    while(T!=Headptr)
    {

        cout<<"Decision Sequence :"<<T->stage<<" / "<<T->Decision<<endl;
        T=T->Parent;
        DecisionSequence[T->stage]=T->Decision;
        cout<<"Decision Sequence :"<<T->Decision<<" ,\t ";
    }
  cout<<"**********************@@@@@DISPLAY ENDED@@@@**************************************"<<endl;

  }
```

[image: This is the Tree Structure]

[image: Decision No 15]

[image: This is Decision no 26]

Comment: You don't like minimal complete examples, do you?

Comment: KillRate multi-dimensional array is getting assigned for 3 values only. And you are asking to display the value for 9*26 different indexes. How did you initialize KillRate array?

Comment: @sgun i want to just keep 3 values and other are intialized to zero and program is just goinf to use these values only as per requirement. And i have intialized array like this: 
KillRate=new double*[26]; 
for(int i=0;i<26;i++) { 
KillRate[i]=new double[9];
 }

Comment: there are two ways I can think of. Either using `calloc` or `memset`. Did you use any of these?

Comment: This is in c++ rather than in c.

Comment: And this is why you do not ever use `new[]`, but instead `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
KillRate = new double*[26]; 
for(int i=0;i<26;i++) { KillRate[i] = new double[9];}
```

This assignment is only allocating memory. So the unassigned addresses will be have arbitrary values.
c++ solution would be:

```
for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
      KillRate[i][j] = 0;
   } 
}
```

Or **faster c solutions**;
use `calloc` or `memset`

Comment: already done this in this function:


 void SetKillRate(double **x)
 {
  
  for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
  {
   for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
   {
    KillRate[i][j]=0;
   }
  }
  KillRate[0][0]=0;
  KillRate[0][1]=.33;
  KillRate[0][2]=.75;


  KillRate[1][0]=0;
  KillRate[1][1]=.33;
  KillRate[1][2]=.75;

  KillRate[2][0]=0;
  KillRate[2][1]=.33;
  KillRate[2][2]=.75;

  KillRate[3][0]=0;
  KillRate[3][1]=.33;
  KillRate[3][2]=.75;

 }

Comment: If your program is single-threaded I can't think of a reason for that issue happening after either one of these solutions.

Comment: thank you so much for ur help problem solved using both calloc and memset together god bless you for helping me bro.

Answer (score 1):

this might be issue due to memory management i encountered same problem and i solved this through making every object into pointer and assigning memory through new i.e. object* KillRate=new object;

Hope this might help